# Input Data in my Combo Box

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I feel really silly asking this question but how do you add any data to a Combo Box? Like I want to display A,B and C as my dropbox strings but I have tried out many things, still my Combo Box does not display anything.

I have tried setting the 'Data' property with A;B;C..still it doesn't show this.

I tried this in my Oninitdialog() function:

```
CComboBox* pComboBox = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_SENSOR_LIST);

    CString string;
    for(int i=0;i<10; i++)
    {
        string.Format("String %d", ++i);
        pComboBox->AddString(string);
    }
```

..
still no change. It may be I might not be doing something really silly but not able to figure it out at the moment. Kindly help.

Cheers.

Comment: I doubt this is going to help much but check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6(v=vs.80).aspx if you notice the string passed to the format function is a unicode string _T("") -> try using that.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: What does your call to pComboBox->AddString(string) return? According to the docs it's an error code and that could give you a better idea of what's happening.
Also have you checked pComboBox is not null......

Comment: Shouldn't it just add an option in the Combo List? Regardless of that, even when I input the variables just by using semicolons after every item, that doesn't work either.

Comment: How do you create the combo box?

Comment: Choose a Combo Box from the dialog editor and place it in my dialog.

Comment: @ExtremeCoder let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2625/discussion-between-nerds-dont-swear-and-extremecoder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your combobox has a height that can hold all entries. The height of a combo box doesn't affect the combo box itself, but the dropdown list.

You can change it in the dialog editor:
Click on the down arrow of the combo box, now there should be a rectangle that allows you to change the height of the combobox dropdown list. Make it large enough to hold all entries.

Comment: Oh my god, this was so easy and I wasted around half my day figuring this out. Thank You so much.